# Meteor js facebook mobile login blank screen

Tags: facebook, meteor

I set up a Facebook login package for my meteor project. It is supposed to work on mobile, but when the iPhone app finishes logging the person into Facebook, it just shows a blank screen.
I have tried:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({loginStyle: "redirect" }
```

But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

The app takes you to the sign in page, but after you sign in, it doesn't redirect back to the app. It just shows a blanks screen.

Comment: More information is needed to diagnose the problem. Give us all points of contact for the login itself. What package are you using?

Comment: I am using package "accounts-facebook". what do you mean by points of contact?

Comment: Like the template and anywhere else the accounts are being accessed in code.

Comment: Also, does the Facebook login work on any other devise with the same code base? Is this an iPhone only issue?

Comment: it is broken on iPhone and android

Comment: Are you getting any errors? For example... You have to sign up with Facebook in order to use login. Have you done that?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Facebook now defaults to API version 2.3 and there is no way to change it to an earlier version in the Facebook App section.

2.3 is not supported by the Facebook accounts system on Meteor.

I just so happens I had an old Facebook app that was set to use API version 2.0

If I didn't have that old app then I would have been out of luck.

If you found this answer useful please arrow up the question and answer. Thanks!